# Google Location History .json in Python

Tags: python, json, location

I'm trying to track my recent activities in Google Location History but can't seem to manage correctly my .json file. Here is the first part of my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import json
from datetime import datetime
from collections import namedtuple
from itertools import takewhile
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim

Point = namedtuple('Point', 'latitude, longitude, datetime')

def read_points():
    with open('Users/Documents/LocationHistory.json') as f:
        data = json.load(f)

    for point in data['locations']:
        yield Point(
            point['latitudeE7'] / 10 ** 7,
            point['longitudeE7'] / 10 ** 7,
            datetime.fromtimestamp(int(point['timestampMs']) / 1000)
        )

points = read_points()
```

Fact is, [points] is empty. Does anyone know why?

Comment: Empty how? An empty list? Have you iterated `points`?

Comment: [points] gives me [None]. No, I haven't iterated. How could I fix that?

Comment: Please post the json file you are reading from so I can see how its formatted

Comment: `{
  "locations" : [ {
    "timestampMs" : "1539413393421",
    "latitudeE7" : 448203162,
    "longitudeE7" : 204594929,
    "accuracy" : 16,
    "altitude" : 157,
    "verticalAccuracy" : 2
  }, {
    "timestampMs" : "1539413093363",
    "latitudeE7" : 448203162,
    "longitudeE7" : 204594929,
    "accuracy" : 16,
    "altitude" : 157,
    "verticalAccuracy" : 2
  }` ,...